# Skip printing to stdout when using "mongo --eval"

Tags: mongodb

I need the js variable to be passed through command line arguments. The option --eval did this. But it also printing the variable value to the shell by default. I want to skip the variable value printed to the shell.

Ex:-
I have used "user_name" inside the script.js
Passing the value using mongo --eval="user_name='john'" script.js

But it un necessarily printing the value

  john

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `--quiet` flag - but evaluated items are still printed to stdout.

You could pipe to /dev/null or a file to capture the stdout eg:

```
mongo --eval="user_name='john'" script.js > /dev/null
```

Comment: thanks ross. but i have redirect the stdout to a specific file for some other purpose, because I have print statement inside js. Found the way that, after re directing the output to a file, remove the evaluated items from the output file.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case you could use `var` in your declaration. This will not print the value:

```
mongo --eval="var user_name='john';" script.js
```